# Making a module change a default behavior without using overrides in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want my PS module to change a default behavior without using overrides. I want to add some element to a ".tpl" file.

Is it possible?

Comment: please explain your requirement or have you tried anything, if so please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hang your functionality from one of the existing hooks. If none of them works for your case, you'll have to create your own hook and add the call into the theme tpl.